# Alternative to adding dynamic view inside of a ViewHolder RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am currently adding ImageViews and setting the images within a ViewHolder. The creation time is not smooth and the first scroll through is not smooth either. Any suggestion or an alternative to having smooth dynamic views within a viewholder?

**ViewHolder**

```
class ViewHolderRecipientExpanded extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private LinearLayout mFlagLayout;
    //

    public ViewHolderRecipientExpanded(View v) {
        super(v);
        mFlagLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.flagLayout);
        //
    }

    public void initiateRecipientsDetails() {
        Recipient recipient = objectList.get(getAdapterPosition());
        int totalAmountOfCountries = recipient.getFlags() != null ? recipient.getFlags().size() : 0;
        // 
        int countriesLimitedToThree = recipient.getFlags() != null ? (totalAmountOfCountries > 3 ? 3 : totalAmountOfCountries) : 0;
        View imageView;
        ImageView image;
        Drawable drawable;
        for (int i = 0; i < countriesLimitedToThree; i++) {
            imageView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_image_flag, null);
            image = (ImageView) imageView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), recipient.getFlags().get(i).getFlag());
            image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            mFlagLayout.addView(imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Load your images [asynchronously](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html), and [cache them in memory](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) when they are not in view. This will not block the UI thread when loading images, allowing the user to scroll even if the images aren't loaded yet. Though, it will still take some time for the images to actually appear.

There are also a number of great libraries that will handle this for you:

- [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
- [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
- [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)